# php auth0 api update app_data

Tags: php, api, token, auth0

I am trying to use auth0 api for php. I strated with this examples:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-php)

Every time when I start I got error that I'm calling non-defined class in dotenv-autoloader `(Dotenv::load(__DIR__);)`. I avoid this and I wrote manually parameter. After that I can create, delete user, change user_metadata, but I can't change app_matadata. Always got same error: `{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing authentication"}`

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what error did you get with Dotenv?

3 things might happened:

- it was not installed (which is weird since it is a dependency in the
  `composer.json` file)
- there was no `.env` file with the configuration
- the `.env` file had the wrong format

Anyway, if you set the configuration manually is enough.

About the `app_metadata` how are you updating it?

this snippet should work:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Auth0\SDK\Auth0Api;

$token = "eyJhbGciO....eyJhdWQiOiI....1ZVDisdL...";
$domain = "account.auth0.com";
$user_id = 'auth0|123...';

$auth0Api = new Auth0Api($token, $domain);

$usersList = $auth0Api->users->update( $user_id, [ "app_metadata" => [ "some_attribute" => "some_value" ] ]);

var_dump($usersList);
```

One important thing, to update the `app_metadata` you need an api token with the `update:users_app_metadata` scope, you can't use the user token for it.